# Google Maps Javascript SDK v3 or switch to Google Maps iOS SDK

Tags: ios, ipad, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

My iOS application is currently using Google Maps JavaScript Application v2 and since its getting deprecated, i have two possible solutions.

There is a need to either upgrade to next version i.e v3 or use the google SDK (say GMSMapView).

Although i can't use apple maps for various reasons.

Both from higher view seems to work, but not worked on both in depth till date.

1. **Upgrading my Google Maps JavaScript Application To v3** :  upgrading to v3 will require rewriting part of my map related code. and since a lot has changed between v2 and v3 of the Google Maps JavaScript API, which is not just an incremental upgrade. So, i need to research changes and check for all requirements are met and changes will not affect anything else.
2. **Google maps SDK** : This will be a complete rework but usage seems more simple than upgrading to newer version and reliable. But don't know how complex it will be later. and all the things done using the Google Maps JavaScript Application v2 should work with SDK too.

Help me in choosing the best solution or tell me if you have any better solution.

Comment: It depends, the time you will spend on doing it, probabbly if you need it faster, just updgrade your tool to v3 because probabbly it will be more complex than using a new tool and you'll do it faster, nevertheless I think using google maps SDK will be the best solution. I'm using apple toolkit with MKMapView and it's very simple to use too, loading kml's (I did a custom kml parser), drawing routes, drawing custom annotations, etc...

Comment: @rokimoki Yes i feel i should buy some time for SDK and fix this issue, so if any new version released the application will not be affected.

Comment: At least in android + google maps sdk, if new version comes and your app is currently in market, your app will not be affected (above all the api key), only with new applications that comes to be developed.

Comment: its not possible to use android + google maps sdk now :P

Comment: I understand, but I don't know about iOS + google maps sdk, I know that apple will do the same with apple toolkit, that I think it's updated or not by iOS version, not by developer tools.